# Pandas: Performance when converting date string to epoch time

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have to parse several csv files with thousands of records and there is a column that represents a date. I am converting it to epoch time as follow:

CSV example:

```
date
2010-07-08 21:24:52
2010-07-08 21:24:53
```

What I am doing now:

```
# First convert column to datetime
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

# Then to epoch time
df.date = pd.to_timedelta(df.date).astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

Because there is a LOT of records, it takes a while to do this conversion. So, the question is, is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: how about `pd.to_datetime(df['date']).astype(np.int64)/1e9`?

Comment: Can you try to assign the RHS values into new columns, and not replace df.date, something like df['date_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date). Since you have large data, when you used df.date = , pandas would have to compare, delete and then add, which might be a costly operation. Just give it a try.

Comment: Thanks guys, tried both things and I got almost the same time, no difference at all.

Comment: you may try to specify the datetime format explicitly - this might save some time: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').astype(np.int64)//1000000000`

Comment: @MaxU thanks, but the time format it's not always the same, that is why I can't specify a format.